# Need to fix switch statement and increasing an integer

Tags: c++

I'm making a very simple proof of concept for my parents and tried to create a simple management game, however, in my switch statement, the second case doesn't increase a material - stone. Any idea why? Any other advice would also be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    bool alive = true;

int stone = 50;
        int money = 20;
        bool wall = false;
    while(alive)
    {

        int MainChoice;

         cout<<endl<<"stone: "<<stone<< " money: "<<money;
        cout <<endl<<"You find yourself as the ruler of a castle what do you do?" << endl<<"1. Build a wall: cost 50 stone"<< endl<<"2. Send out miners:gets 50 stone"<< endl<<"3. Oppress the people"<<endl;

        cin>>MainChoice;
        //Main Menu Choices
        switch(MainChoice)
        {
        //Build the wall
        case 1:
            if(stone>=50)
            {
                cout<<"You build the wall";
                wall = true;
                stone - 50;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Insuffcient Stone";
            }
            break;
        //Send out miners
        case 2:
            stone + 50;
            cout<< "Gathered stone";
            break;
        // Oppress the people
        case 3:
            if(wall == false)
            {
                alive = false;
                cout<<"You get killed in the riot";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<< "The wall saves you from death";
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"im sorry that doesnt seem to be correct";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you, and sorry for the messy code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that these lines:

```
   stone - 50;
   ...
   stone + 50;
```

just calculate the result of the expression and then throws it away. There is no assignment. You could change them to:

```
   stone -= 50;
   ...
   stone += 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

For increasing your variable's value, you can use one of the concepts below:

```
stone += 50;
```

or

```
stone = stone + 50;
```

Comment: And `++stone` to increase only to one unit.